# Backpacking with visa B2 in USA

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, backpacking, french-citizens

I have quit my job recently to travel the world in a few months. I am planning to visit the USA as my first step and would like to stay there for at least 4 months. So I have applied for a tourist visa (B2).

From what I can read on different websites, I see many people getting their visa refused because they cannot show enough ties with their home countries (married, children, property, promise of employment).

I don't have any of these and getting worried as I cannot see anyone with similar experience. I am young, wishing to travel the world. And it is precisely because I don't have those ties that I can do it. I have prepared a sheet with details of my itinerary, budget and contact details of every hostels I'll stay in. Also bank statements showing sufficient funds. But that's all I have basically.

I have my appointment with the embassy in a few days.
If anyone has some advices - which would help me support my application to the consular officer - it would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is your nationality? If you are from a country eligible for the [VWP](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html), you don't need a B2 visa at all, and no need to interview (but you can only stay up to 3 months).

Comment: I am french so you are right about the VWP. But I would like more than 3 months so I have enough time to visit both coasts with no rush. That is why I am choosing the B2. Do you think that would seem odd or difficult to prove?

Comment: Travel within the US is easy, and daily expenses tend to be high, so you may do well to just stay up to 90 days and spend more time in other countries.  Canada is great, especially since you're French!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on numerous reports, the US consulates around the world seem to be fairly strict in issuing B2 visas to people from Visa Waiver Program countries - especially younger people and/or those without a good reason to need more than the VWP offers beyond "I want to stay for more than 3 months".

You really have 2 options :

- Use the VWP, and stay less than the 90 days that it allows you
- Apply for a B2, and risk being rejected. If you are rejected, then you will almost certainly NOT be allowed enter the country using the VWP for at least 1-2 years afterwards.

Personally I would recommend going with the first option...

Comment: Technically being refused a visa no longer makes you ineligible for VWP - as long as you can obtain an ESTA then you can enter under the VWP program, even if you've previously been refused a visa.  However, if the visa refusal is recent, the odds of an ESTA being granted within (at least) the first year is basically zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarifying the risk. Indeed I have seen the [statistics](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/RefusalRates/FY14.pdf) and the refusal rate for french people is 18.8%

Comment: (+1) Since the OP apparently already applied, is it possible to pull this application to avoid lowering the odds of getting an ESTA or has that ship sailed?

Comment: Once you've applied there's no way to withdraw the application. However I suspect that (at the time the question was asked) the OP had not actually "applied", but instead had just made an appointment for an interview and potentially filled in the relevant paperwork (eg, DS160). At that point, no actual application has been made - that only happens at the interview - and he could easily cancel the appointment or simply not show up and it would not be considered a negative.